# Не удается запустить менеджер геометрии

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter

Пытаюсь я такой создать scrollbar для своего г программы и не удается запустить службу геометрию Python (Г означает GUI Графический интерфейс пользователя).

По крайней мере так Google Translate переводит эту ошибку.

```python
import os
from tkinter import *

MyGUIinterface = Tk()

folderpathget = StringVar()


MyGUIinterface.title("LSTIR Pratotype")

MyGUIinterface.geometry('600x500')

txt = Entry(MyGUIinterface, textvariable = folderpathget ,width=50)

txt.grid(column=2, row=0)



def clicked():
    folderpathget_string =os.listdir(folderpathget.get())


    i = 0
    stringconvert = ''
    while i < len(folderpathget_string):

        stringconvert += folderpathget_string[i] + "\n"
        i += 1
    folderpath = Message(MyGUIinterface, text=stringconvert)
    folderpath.grid(columnspan=1)

#scroll bar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(MyGUIinterface)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )

mylist = Listbox(MyGUIinterface, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
for line in range(100):
   mylist.insert(END)

mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
scrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview )


btn = Button(MyGUIinterface, text="enter the folder path and click me", command = clicked )

btn.grid(column = 0, row=0)


MyGUIinterface.mainloop()
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
>   scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )
>    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2140, in pack_configure 
>    + self._options(cnf, kw))
>  _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid
> ```

Comment: Могли бы написать "для своей гуёвой программы" - мы бы поняли. GUI именуется как гуйня.

Comment: А вообще, следовало бы писать полную ошибку, а не понравившийся кусок.

Comment: Вот полная ошибка

Comment: Как хорошо, что её добавил кто-то, а не вы, да?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) на Tkinter:

> Never mix grid and pack in the same master window. Tkinter will happily spend the rest of your lifetime trying to negotiate a solution that both managers are happy with. Instead of waiting, kill the application, and take another look at your code. A common mistake is to use the wrong parent for some of the widgets.

Т.е. не следует использовать менеджеры `grid` и `pack` в одном родительском окне. Так что я бы рекомендовал везде использовать либо только `grid`, либо только `pack`. После того, как я заменил все `grid` на `pack`, у меня всё заработало.